# Conditional update of a field from another field in the same record

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a field if its value is equal to `NULL` using a value from another field in the same record but it is not working and it is not giving me any errors as well. I tried these two queries and they do not do the job!

```
update tracking 
inner join ( select `ID`, `start_date` from tracking where `ID` =20212) t2
ON tracking.`ID` = t2.`ID`
SET `design date`="2019-01-19",
`design date original`= IF(`design date original` = NULL,t2.`start_date`, `design date original`) 
where tracking.`ID` =20212
```

'

```
update tracking 
SET `design date`="2019-01-19",
`design date original`= IF(`design date original` = NULL,`start_date`, `design date original`) 
where `ID` =20212
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `<expr> = NULL` is never true, even if `<expr>` is `NULL`. To check if for `NULL`, use `IS NULL`: `<expr> IS NULL`.
- But you don't even need an `if()` here. There is a special function, `coalesce()`, that returns the first non-null expression from the list of its arguments.
- Don't use double quotes to enclose string literals. Though MySQL accepts that in general, it can cause unwanted results, as double quotes in SQL are actually meant to enclose identifiers (e.g. column names). So it's better to always use single quotes around string literals.
- And identifiers (column names) with spaces in them are possible, but aren't the best idea either. If you want to save you some possible trouble, don't use them.

```
UPDATE `tracking`
       SET `design date` = '2019-01-19',
           `design date original` = coalesce(`design date original`,
                                             `start_date`) 
       WHERE `ID` = 20212;
```